# Django custom admin template access GET parameters

Tags: django

I want to create custom django admin template and pass there some data. Is it possible to access GET query in custom template ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The request object should be injected into all templates, so yes, you can access the `GET` dictionary.

```
{{ request.GET.my_param }}
```

Comment: I try to print out value of get request by creating the following template https://www.dropbox.com/s/37o6ywocu3biapj/Screenshot%202017-06-07%2022.59.53.png?dl=0 . admin form prints out, but my_param - not

Comment: Can you double check that `'django.template.context_processors.request'` is in your TEMPLATE context_processors setting?

Comment: Interesting. And your url has the parameter in it? somehting like this? `/admin/something?my_param=something`

Comment: yes, like this 127.0.0.1:8000/admin/core/orderingsettings/?my_param=hello. after request submit it looks like http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/core/orderingsettings/?e=1

Comment: That is odd. you should be able to access it through `{{ request.GET.e }}`

Comment: oh i'm sorry i was checking wrong template. works like a charm. thanks!